# Where I can find libjsc.so and libjscexecutor.so to download?

Tags: android, react-native, ubuntu-touch, waydroid

I'm running Waydroid on my Ubuntu Touch phone OS.
The vast majority of the apps are working just fine.
This one application unfortunately crashes on start up because it can't find these 2 libraries. I've noticed that by looking at the waydroid logcat.
It seems they’re expected to be at either /system/lib64 or /vendor/lib64, or maybe packaged with the app itself.
Either way, the app crashes on startup. I've tried contacting the support for that app but it seems they don't know how to fix it, so I was wondering if I could just copy the files myself to my phone?